# Visual Studio 2013 compilation error - missing file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I get an error when I compile my project with VS2013:

In French `Impossible de copier le fichier "obj\Debug\mySoft.exe", car il est introuvable.`

In English it should be something like `Impossible to copy file ... because it doesn't exist`

- I checked all my compilation settings
- I restarted VS2013, my computer => nothing changes
- I checked the rights on different output folders => everything seems to be ok
- I tried to compile other projects => it works

If you have any idea, please help me.

Comment: Make sure that the project is enabled to be built in the Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, so the solution ;-)

Antivirus has detected that my .exe was a virus and deleted the file when it has been created in obj folder, that why compilator can't copy the file in bin folder !

I add an exception in my antivir software parameters to solve the issue.

Thanks for your help

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete obj folder? It will be regenerated on build